# Getting 5 worst of each group in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a code in SQL where I am trying to get the top 5 worst for each function. I would like it to just grab the 5 worst for each group not the 5 worst overall. The code is as follows:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT Job_Function, CMX_DSC_TE, MGR_ANW_CD_Num - DES_LVL_NR_Num AS JSC_Gap
FROM  dbo.AC_GLN_Project_JSC
ORDER BY Job_Function, JSC_Gap
```

The table looks like: (This is a smaller version)

```
AG  Air Operations Tools and Equipment Knowledge    -2
AG  Capacity Planning Knowledge                     -1
AG  Conducts Research                                 -3
AG  Equipment Repair Management                     -4
AG    
AG  Equipment Repair Management                     -3
AG  Facilities, Equipment, and Grounds Maintenance  -3
AG  Facilities, Equipment, and Grounds Maintenance  -2
AG  Instructional Design Knowledge                      -2
AG  Plans Flight Operations                     -1
AG  Statistical Analysis    -2
AG  Troubleshoots Aircraft Failures            0
AG  Vendor/Supplier Management                       -3
AUTOMOTIVE  Automotive Engineering Knowledge    -1
AUTOMOTIVE  Budget Management   -3
AUTOMOTIVE  Labor Relations Knowledge   -3
AUTOMOTIVE  Mechanical Knowledge    -3
AUTOMOTIVE  Mechanical Knowledge    -3
AUTOMOTIVE  Mechanical Knowledge    -2
AUTOMOTIVE  Applies Marketing Knowledge     0
AUTOMOTIVE  Applies Service, Product, and Customer Technology Knowledge -3
```

I Need it to look like:

```
AG Equipment Repair Management -4
AG Facilities, Equipment, and Grounds Maintenance -3
AG Conducts Research -3
AG VEndor Supply Management - 3
AG Air Operations Tools and Equipment Knowledge -2
AUTO Labor Relations Knowledge -3
AUTO Budget Management -3
AUTO Mechanical Knowledge -3
AUTO Applies Service, Product, and Customer Technology Knowledge    -3
AUTO Automotive Engineering Knowledge -1
```

Even if the same CMX_DSC_TE repeats the exact same score I only need one of them listed.

Comment: What is your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your requirements on a group are not exactly clear but it sounds like you want the return the 5 worst `jsc_gaps` for each `job_function`.  If I interpreted that correctly, then you should be able to use `row_number()` and partition the data by the `job_function` and order it by the `jsc_gap`:

```
select 
  Job_Function, 
  CMX_DSC_TE, 
  JSC_Gap
from
(
  select 
    Job_Function, 
    CMX_DSC_TE, 
    MGR_ANW_CD_Num - DES_LVL_NR_Num AS JSC_Gap,
    row_number() over(partition by job_function
                      order by MGR_ANW_CD_Num - DES_LVL_NR_Num) seq
  FROM  dbo.AC_GLN_Project_JSC
) d
where seq <= 5
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7011f/3)

Based on your edit you should be able to use:

```
;with cte as 
(
  select 
    Job_Function, 
    CMX_DSC_TE, 
    JSC_Gap = MGR_ANW_CD_Num - DES_LVL_NR_Num,
    row_number() over(partition by Job_Function, CMX_DSC_TE
                      order by MGR_ANW_CD_Num - DES_LVL_NR_Num, CMX_DSC_TE) seq
  FROM  dbo.AC_GLN_Project_JSC
)
select Job_Function, 
    CMX_DSC_TE, 
    JSC_Gap
from
(
  select Job_Function, 
    CMX_DSC_TE, 
    JSC_Gap,
    row_number() over(partition by Job_Function
                      order by JSC_Gap, CMX_DSC_TE) rn
  from cte
  where seq = 1
) d
where rn <= 5;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/be533/36)

Comment: This is actually returning duplicates of the CMX_DSC_TE, any thoughts how to revise it?

Comment: @user2119980 My suggestion would be to edit the sql fiddle with your actual data.  You didn't provide the clearest requirements in the first place.

Comment: @user2119980 You never specified what the groups are supposed to be, what exactly are your requirements?

Comment: THe 5 lowest scoring categories from each Job_Function: The Categories are the CMX_DSC_TE and the scores are the JSC_Gap

Comment: @user2119980 You might want to add `CMX_DSC_TE` to the `partition by`, but I am guessing here because you have not been very clear with what you data is like

Comment: THe Job_Function are various groups in the company, the CMX_DSC_TE are competencies relating to various jobs, and the JSC_Gap is the difference between the desired score and the score the manager gives an employee

Comment: So basically what I need is the 5 lowest CMS_DSC_TE for each Job_function, they lowest scoring JSC_Gap. They each have to be different.

Comment: @user2119980 How about you edit your original question with your table structure, some sample data and the desired result?